# Event Loop and promises

Tags: javascript, event-loop

When I am running below code in the console, I am getting output as:

```
"start"
"Promise 2"
"end"
"Promise 1"
```

```js
console.log("start");
Promise.resolve().then(
  () => console.log("Promise 1")
).then(console.log("Promise 2"));
console.log("end");
```

Can anyone explain to me why "Promise 2" is printed before "Promise 1" and "end"?

Answer (score 4):

The argument to `.then()` should be a function. But you wrote `.then(console.log("Promise 2"))`, and `console.log("Promise 2")` is a function call, not a function. It's executed immediately, so the log message is displayed immediately, not when the promise is resolved.

Change it to a function, like you have around `console.log("Promise 1")`, and they'll be executed in the expected order.

```js
console.log("start");
Promise.resolve().then(
  () => console.log("Promise 1")
).then(() => console.log("Promise 2"));
console.log("end");
```

`end` is logged first because promise resolution is asynchronous.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out, you should pass `console.log` as a function to have it run in the correct order.

As for the reason for `end` displaying first, it is because the event loop will make sure the call stack is empty and all global executions are complete before it checks the micro-task queue (sometimes called the job queue) where your console logs are sitting waiting to be added to the call stack.

It's about priorities (in descending order of priority):

- Global thread of execution
- Micro-task/job queue
- Task queue

The `start` and `end` are in the global thread of execution so will run first. The event loop will then add `Promise 1` and `Promise 2` logs from the micro-task queue and run them after all global executions are finished. Finally if the micro-task queue is empty, the event loop will check the task queue (things like `setTimeout` get added here).

Hope that helps.

Comment: This article has some further reading on the subject of task/micro-task queues: https://jakearchibald.com/2015/tasks-microtasks-queues-and-schedules/